# Can I set attributes before constructor when creating HTMLElement programmatically?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have something like this...

```
class Thing extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.selected = this.getAttribute('selected');
    ...
  }
}
```

This works fine when creating the element like `<my-thing selected="thing"></my-thing>`. Now I want to inject a list of things. I could do it like this...

```
this.things.forEach((thing)=>{
  tabString += `<my-thing selected=${thing.selected}></my-thing>`;
});
```

and then inject into inner HTML but this seems hacky. What I would really like to do is something like this...

```
this.things.forEach((thing)=>{
  this.element.appendChild(new Thing());
});
```

But how would I set `selected`?

I still need to be able to add the component as a normal tag in HTML as well and it should handle the attribute either way.

Comment: You can't set properties of an object before it is instantiated. There's nothing to set properties of.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass `selected` in the constructor:

```
class Thing extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(selected){
    super();
    this.selected = selected || this.getAttribute('selected');
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying the constructor is not ran till the element is appended?

Comment: @JGleason Is it important that `selected` is set before the constructor runs?

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for I still want to be able to set from the attribute in a normal tag as well. How does this handle <my-thing selected="thingy"></my-thing> as well?

Comment: @JGleason The code overwrites `selected` after the element is created. I don’t think there is a way to set the attribute before the element is created.

Comment: That is fine and may be the answer, that there is no way to do it.

Comment: @JGleason I updated the answer. Is this what you’re looking for?

Comment: For diagram of which CE methods run when see: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/